# Symbolic expectation of sum of N random variables

Tags: python, statistics, sympy

From https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html#examples, the following code calculates the expectation of the sum of two dice.

```
from sympy.stats import P, E, variance, Die, Normal
from sympy import Eq, simplify, symbols
X, Y = Die('X', 6), Die('Y', 6) # Define two six sided dice
E(X+Y) # Expectation of the sum of two dice
```

However, I want to calculate the expectation of sum of N dice, which N is a symbol, like

```
N = symbols('N')
```

Is this possible?

I want the **symbolic** result, not one calculated through Monte Carlo simulation.

Edit: N is unknown, so it should be treated as an variable in the result.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Comment: No. Thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 1):

The pmf/pdf of the sum of independent variables is the convolution of the pmf/pdf of each variable. For discrete variables, the convolution is just a finite summation of the elements of the pmf, and for dice, it's even simpler, since the elements are all equal to 1/(number of faces). The hard part is getting the limits of the summation correct -- something to watch out for.

Once you have the summation in hand, you can try some identities on it. I'm not sure what's possible there, but you can certainly get at least that far.

EDIT: I didn't read carefully enough. If you're only interested in the expected value of the sum, then it's much simpler. E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y], so the question reduces to calculating the expected value for one die. This, again, is a summation, and simpler than the convolution.

Be that as it may, on thinking about it some more, a symbolic solution for the pmf of a sum of dice is probably going to be pretty messy. Some years ago I worked out the pdf of a sum of uniform continuous variables -- it turns out to be a piecewise polynomial, with the number of pieces increasing with the number of dice (I seem to recall it's m where m is the number of dice). I suspect something similar is in store for the sum of dice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to sum `n` Dice in the case `n` is a given constant. As mentioned elsewhere, the expected value is quite straightforward: `n` times the expected value of one die (so, `7*n/2`).

Calculating the `density` (probability mass function) quickly becomes messy and very slow. For `n=10` it gives a memory overflow on my system.

```py
from sympy.stats import Die, P, E, variance, density

def sympy_listsum(die_list):
    res =  die_list[0]
    for d in die_list[1:]:
        res += d
    return res

n = 5
X = sympy_listsum([ Die(f'Die_{k}', 6) for k in range(n)] )

print(X)
print(E(X))
print(P(X < 10))
print(variance(X))
print(density(X))
```

Result for `n=5`:

```
Die_0 + Die_1 + Die_2 + Die_3 + Die_4
35/2
7/432
175/12
{5: 1/7776, 6: 5/7776, 7: 5/2592, 8: 35/7776, 9: 35/3888, 10: 7/432, 11: 205/7776, 12: 305/7776, 13: 35/648, 14: 5/72, 15: 217/2592, 16: 245/2592, 17: 65/648, 18: 65/648, 19: 245/2592, 20: 217/2592, 21: 5/72, 22: 35/648, 23: 305/7776, 24: 205/7776, 25: 7/432, 26: 35/3888, 27: 35/7776, 28: 5/2592, 29: 5/7776, 30: 1/7776}
```